# checkbox is not displaying in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the checkbox dynamically on a button click event. I have written the code like

```
 $("button").on('click',function(){
  $(".chkbx").each(function(){
       $(this).show(); 
  });
 });


 $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({                                        
        checkboxes: {
               checkChildren: true,
               template: " # if(item.categoryid == 0){ }  else { #  <input type='checkbox'  id='#= item.haschildren #-#= item.categoryid #'  name='chkbox' class='chkbx' />#}#"
          },    
          dataSource: initial,
          dataTextField: ["categoryname"]                      
  });
```

this code is working in chrome but not working in firefox.

Comment: please make a working fiddle with your code -> www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please add the HTML to review.

Comment: Also, make sure this is enclosed within `$(document).on("ready", (function({`

Comment: When you press control+shift+k you can see the console. In your code you can log something to the console. In your code try: `console.log("checkboxes:",$(".checkbox"));` I don't think you need each, you can do: $(".chkbox").show()`

Comment: I have already tried $(".chkbx").show(); but no use

Comment: @HMR in chrome it showing how many check boxes are there and in ff it is showing the object object in the console

Comment: @Jonathan, you added more javascript, but no HTML.

Comment: @Jonathan You should be able to click on the [object Object] to see it's details. If that doesn't work you can install the firebug plug in and open that by pressing F12 You could try to move your script to the end of the body: `...htmlcode <script src="..."></body>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the normal [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function of jQuery. It isn't necessary to handle a each function, a show() at the element would be enough.

Here an example: [jsFiddle](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

**EDIT**

 Your code actually just works in firefox, chrome and IE for me. Though you might find the fiddle usefull.